# Change the default folder icon inYUI 3 Treeview

Tags: css, treeview, icons, yui

The default icon in the tree view (using gallery-yui-treeview)  is  a folder icon with an arrow or a page icon . I want to change this to a plus/minus sign. I guess something needs to be done to the skin used but I am not able to figure out what and how. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page about YUI skinning : http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tutorials/skins/

Create your own sprite with the folder you want to display (default is : tree_view_icons_blue_01_arrow_beside_folders.gif )

Then, override the span displaying the folder like this :

```
<style>
.yui3-treeview-label-content{
    background-image: url("my_new_folder_sprite.png");
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks !! But I switched from YUI to other js library because of offline support and related issues.